Altium Database Library Problem for Component System Parameter
I set the "Component Kind" system parameter of the components in my database library such as "Standard (No BOM), Net Tie and also other system parameters such as Description, Comment and etc.
After I place a component from the library on the schematic, all parameters are set correctly as you can see in the "Parameter Table" in following picture but the component "Type" does not obey from the "Component Kind" parameter as seen from "Properties" panel in the picture.

Why does this problem occure?
Thanks.

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).
